# How to calculate Node Allocatable Resources for Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: memory-management, kubernetes, resources, cpu, scaling

We have a cluster where nodes are out of resources leading to slowness and over-committing issues. This is forcing us to restart the nodes frequently. We are planning to enforce a node allocatable resource policy to split the available CPU, Memory and Ephemeral Storage between system, kubelet, and application pods.

Came across some guidelines on allocatable resource calculation [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-architecture).

It does not specify how much is the split between system and kubelet resources. Also, we are on open shift and so not sure how much of this is applicable.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned you are using `OpenShift` and docs you provided are from GCP. Default requirements, parameters might be differnt due to Cloud Provider specs.

Unfortunately I am not `OpenShift` user, but you can find in OS [documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.2/admin_guide/allocating_node_resources.html) that:

Resources reserved for node components are based on two node settings: `kube-reserved` and `system-reserved`.

You can set these in the kubeletArguments section of the node configuration file (the */etc/origin/node/node-config.yaml* file by default) using a set of = pairs (e.g., cpu=200m,memory=512Mi).

**How to compute Allocated Resources?**

An allocated amount of a resource is computed based on the following formula:

`[Allocatable] = [Node Capacity] - [kube-reserved] - [system-reserved]`

If `[Allocatable]` is negative, it is set to 0.

Please check below OpenShift docs: [Allocating node resources](https://docs.okd.io/latest/admin_guide/allocating_node_resources.html), [Capacity management](https://blog.openshift.com/full-cluster-capacity-management-monitoring-openshift/), [Cluster Limits](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/scaling_performance/cluster_limits.html), [Resource Limits](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/dev_guide/limits.html)

Many factors depends on what exactly pods/images you want to use. Some images might requested 0.1 CPU but others might need 1CPU to start.

You can limit it by create a [Quota](https://docs.openshift.com/online/dev_guide/compute_resources.html), set `Pod` [requests and limits](https://www.magalix.com/blog/kubernetes-resource-requests-and-limits-101).

Please keep in mind that you can always check current Requests/Limits in each Pod, under the Containers.containerName.Requests:

```
$ os describe pod <pod-name>
```

Or requested resources / limits on node

```
$ os describe node <node-name>
```

On the bottom of this description you should get All pods reqyest and limits

```
Non-terminated Pods:         (6 in total)
  Namespace                  Name                                              CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  AGE
  ---------                  ----                                              ------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
  default                    nginx-7cdbd8cdc9-b94r9                            100m (10%)    0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         6m2s
  default                    nginx-7cdbd8cdc9-nlsw7                            100m (10%)    0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         6m2s
  kube-system                fluentd-gcp-v3.2.0-lwnqn                          100m (10%)    1 (106%)    200Mi (7%)       500Mi (18%)    5h22m
  kube-system                kube-proxy-gke-stc1-default-pool-094e5c74-4dzj    100m (10%)    0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         5h22m
  kube-system                prometheus-to-sd-lbj57                            1m (0%)       3m (0%)     20Mi (0%)        20Mi (0%)      5h22m
  kube-system                traefik-749d86f748-frs7q                          0 (0%)        0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         158m
Allocated resources:
  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
  Resource                   Requests    Limits
  --------                   --------    ------
  cpu                        401m (42%)  1003m (106%)
  memory                     220Mi (8%)  520Mi (19%)
  ephemeral-storage          0 (0%)      0 (0%)
  attachable-volumes-gce-pd  0           0
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: @Caledor if my answer helped you, could you upvote it or accept? Or if you still have any questions or doubts let me know.