# node resource usage in openshift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

Can somebody clarify me regarding oc adm top command in openshift. As per redhat (https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3654511) top command will show resources available. But in my cluster it is not the case.

```
#oc adm top nodes

node2   3166m        6%        102920Mi        82%
```

here it is showing memory is 82% used. But when I log in to server I see different values.

```
#free
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:      131857820    52185484     2347628       42496    77324708    78817524
```

usage is around 52% .

Am I reading this wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

[Kubectl top nodes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#top) as like as [oc adm top nodes](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/admin_guide/manage_nodes.html#viewing-nodes) rely on information from [cgroups](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide/ch01).

[Free](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/free.1.html) , [top](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html) and other native linux tools rely on information from [procps](http://procps.sourceforge.net/)

detailed information is here:

- [Memory inside Linux
  containers](https://fabiokung.com/2014/03/13/memory-inside-linux-containers/)
- [Why top and free inside containers don't show the correct container
  memory](https://ops.tips/blog/why-top-inside-container-wrong-memory/)

Comment: Hi VKR, thanks for info.  I'm new to this cgroups and linux namespaces. So do I need to worry about node memory usage?  I didn't configured kube-reserved, system-reserved in my node-config.yaml. I think I will get resource unavailable issues soon? Please clarify me.

Comment: of course  you should worry about that, as incorrectly calculated resources will lead to problems in the future. Check also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58065712/9929015